# tapply of two variables in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

My data :

```
TEST <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(22L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("month", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "")))
```

and :

```
month <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

I want to sum by row, so I used this code :

```
su_test <- list()
for (i in 1:ncol(TEST)){
    su_test[[i]] <- tapply(TEST[,i], month, sum)
}

su_test <- do.call(cbind, su_test)
```

and to check the quantile :

```
su_test_obs <- apply(su_test,1,quantile,c(0.1,0.9))
```

This is an observation simulation per month. However I also have the detail by area. :

```
TEST2 <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1), .Dim = c(22L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("month", 
"area", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "")))

area <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

I would like to have the same result of `su_test_obs` 
but with the details of the areas in addition like `list(month, area)` but I don't understand the logic. 
Would you have a solution please? Maybe there is a solution simpler with `dplyr`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much simpler if you convert your matrix to dataframe. We can then use `aggregate` which can be applied to multiple groups easily

```
df <- data.frame(TEST2)
apply(aggregate(.~month + area, df, sum)[-c(1, 2)], 1, quantile, c(0.1,0.9))

#    [,1] [,2]
#10%    2  1.7
#90%    6  5.3
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfectly work. But I realize that I need an object like "su_test" to make histograms distributions of my simulation `ggplot type simulations (data.frame (x = su_test[1,]), aes (x = x)) +
geom_histogram (bins = 30, col = 'black', fill = 'white')`. Do you think it is possible to reestablish a `su_test` with my 2 variables? thank you

Comment: @thomasleon `su_test` is `aggregate(.~month + area, df, sum)` whereas `su_test_obs` is `apply(aggregate(.~month + area, df, sum)[-c(1, 2)], 1, quantile, c(0.1,0.9))`